# Angular2 - get argument from url with skipLocationChange

Tags: angular

I dont know how to transfer data between requests (components). I need transfer error from any component to ErrorComponent and show error message and http state code. 
I try this:

```
this.router.navigate(['/error', { error: error }], { skipLocationChange: true });
```

But I dont know how to get error argument from url (error argument isnt in browser). I know when skipLocationChange = false, i see error in url, but I do not want to see it.
How to transfer error from errorhandler to errorcomponent for show error message? How do i know which http error code i have?
Thanks

Comment: you can use service for transfer error message between two component. refer this link https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Thanks, thats good. But I have next problem. My service has property error which type is Error. And now i need show http status code. In http.get() i 'll get it code 404. I created class HttpError with property code, but when i cast property error in service, i have still Error and i dont know status code.

Comment: why don't you send the error code along with the data part in the router .navigate function so that you need not parse it later . i:e send it as a string

Comment: Can you show me how? Thanks

Comment: @bluray hope tghis helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way from app.routing file

```
@RouteConfig([
    {path: '/error', component: ErrorComponent,
     as: 'Error', data: {error: '404' // or your component variable the info you get from service}}])

export class ErrorComponent{
    error: string;
    constructor(params: RouteParams, data: RouteData) {
        this.productID = params.get('error');

        console.log('Error is ', data.get('error'));
    }
}
```

or

in the component use like this

```
this.router.navigate(['/a4',{message:"Not Authorised"}]);
```

and in the error component access the value like

```
this.message = this.route.snapshot.params['message']; //you can even subscribe to the value here to listen for changes
```

Comment: Thank you, but i have small questions. I dont understand any parts of your example. In route config you have data {error: 404} but from server i get different status codes, 404, 400, 401... How to add code which i get from server? In second example, you have message, I would like send error message, status code, maybe callstack (for debugging) but i wouldnt show this data in url. I am sorry, I am newbie in angular2. Thanks :)

Comment: that is another way , when you send static data from you app.routing . if you want to send any data that changes send via the this.router.navigate(['/a4',{message:"Not Authorised"}]); change the message value instead of string use a variable

Comment: yes, i know that i write in errorhandler something like this ([ '/ a4', {message: error.message, statusCode: error.statusCode, error: error}]); but this data i see in url, this is good way or not?

Comment: if you want data to not to be seen in url then send data via services to the component or use the data attribute of router ,
{ path: 'a4/', component:  Angular4Component, data:{ ping:'passed via router'}}

But i am not sure if this can be acheived via router you might need to check

Comment: I found a link it can be achived using router resolve check 

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#fetch-before-navigating

Comment: hope it helps , you can fetch the data before the router loads or resolves